# FACEBOOK:: Read images from a public fan page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to extract images from a FB fan page.
I'm able to read the page post, I then check post by post to see if it is really a photo and then try to open the object_id related to photo.
The last point give me error: it told me I need an user token.
I'm developing an automated script that needs to work every 10 mins and downlad new data.
I'm not admin of the page.
Is there a solution?
thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the issue - have your user come back once every 60 days, get a [long-lived access token](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) for them, store it, and use that token to read the page's `/feed` connection

You can also use an [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) if the page has no demographic restrictions

Comment: Just to be sure: is this url [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) the url with the example code I need or is it different for getting a long lasting token?

Comment: btw the /feed connection is ok with the app access token
With the same token I can also read the content of the specific post.
I need the user access for reading the object_id related to the photo of a single post.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah that's it, the server-side flow will give you a token valid for up to 60 days

Comment: Perfect. a simple solution to a big problem (for me).

Comment: just found that the call works only if I'm logged into Facebook: is it correct from your side?